# What is difference between default and custom serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

What is default and custom serialization ?
Default serialization is appropriate if physical and logical representation aren't differ and if aren't it need to use custom serialization.
But I couldn't get what's really default and custom.

```
//Default serialization form :`
    public final class StringList implements Serializable {
        private int size = 0;
        private Entry head = null;
    }
    private static class Entry implements Serializable {
        String data;
        Entry next;
        Entry previous;
    }
    ... // Remainder omitted
}

//Custom serialization form
    public final class StringList implements Serializable {
        private transient int size = 0;
        private transient Entry head = null;

    // No longer Serializable
    private static class Entry {
        String data;
        Entry next;
        Entry previous;
    }
}
```

So is there well explained example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization is the process of mapping an object to a serial representation. If you want to serialize an object, its class must implement `Serializable`.

In your default form, both classes with all their fields will be serialized. However, in your custom form the `transient` modifier in `StringList` indicates that the corresponding fields `size` and `head` will **not be serialized**. Note, that the class itself will be serialized, simply without those fields. As `Entry` does not implement `Serializable`, it cannot be serialized anymore as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

The default serialization uses the default rule to do serialization.
All `Serializable` and not transient fields are serialized.
To be a  `Serializable` class, the class has to implement the `Serializable` interface. If you try to serialize a object which the class doesn't derive from   `Serializable` or an object which owns at least a field which the class doesn't derive from the `Serializable` interface and the field has not the transient modifier, a exception will occur at runtime to indicate a serialization error if you serialize the object.

If you don't want that the default rule be applied for all fields, you can define  the fields to ignore for serialization with the transient modifier and you can also not implement the `Serializable` interface in the classes of these fields (if you have the hand on them). Not implementing the `Serializable` interface is not mandatory but as an exception occurs if you try to serialize a not `Serializable` field, it allows to protect you if you forget to apply the transient modifier to the field.

Finally, when you disable some fields for serialization, this fields are not saved in the serialized output. So, you don't retrieve them when you unserialize the data you serialized.

In your example with the custom serialization form, nothing is serialized in the class as all fields are transient while in the first example with default serialization, all fields (`size` and `head`) are serialized.